# list all the packages installed in venv

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

How do i list all the packages installed in virtual Environment (venv)? I know pip list shows all packages globally from my computer, but I just want to see from venv folder.

I tried pip freeze and pip list but it shows all the packages from my whole system not the venv folder.

Comment: `pip freeze -l` when your venv is active.

Comment: You can execute `pip` from your virtual env: `venv/bin/pip list` (or `freeze`)

Comment: you can try `pip list --local`

Comment: pip list --local | tail -n +3 | awk '{print $1"=="$2}' > requirements.txt

Answer (score 0):

If `pip` is listing the system Python's packages then the venv isn't activated.

Activate the venv:

```bash
source venv/bin/activate
```

verify that the venv is activated:

```bash
% which pip
path/to/venv/bin/pip
```

then `pip freeze` will work as expected.